# ko.observableArray is not accepting an array in TypeScript that is an array type

Tags: knockout.js, typescript2.0

Running the Knockout tutorial through TypeScript to get a better sense of it, I'm getting an error:  "JavaScript runtime error: The argument passed when initializing an observable array must be an array, or null, or undefined." 
Tried a few things, this is where I'm at currently and certainly I'm missing something. My Primary intent is to better understand ObservableArrays inside of TypeScript. The failure is on line 25 of the TS code. The 'initialMeal' argument contains the array object but the 'meal' property rejects it.

```js
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />

module Home {
    export class Index {
        name: KnockoutObservable<string>;
        availableMeals: any[];
        meal: KnockoutObservableArray<InitialMeal>;
        seats: KnockoutObservableArray<any>;

        constructor() {
            let self = this;

            // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
            self.availableMeals = [
                { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
                { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
                { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
            ];
        }

        seatReservation(name: string, initialMeal: InitialMeal): void {
            let self = this;
            self.name = ko.observable(name);
            self.meal = ko.observableArray(initialMeal);
        }

        reservationsViewModel() {
            let self = this;

            // Editable data
            self.seats = ko.observableArray([
                self.seatReservation("Bob", self.availableMeals[1]),
                self.seatReservation("Stan", self.availableMeals[0])
            ]);
        }
    }

    interface InitialMeal extends Array<any> {
        mealName: string;
        price: number;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    let vm = new Home.Index();
    ko.applyBindings(vm.reservationsViewModel());
});
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Passenger name</th>
                    <th>Meal</th>
                    <th>Surcharge</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
                <tr>
                    <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: meal().mealName"></td>
                    <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want `meal` to be an array?

Comment: You aren't giving it an array. You're setting it to initialMeal which is a single InitialMeal object. If you wrap that in brackets then it becomes an array, but similarly to Michael Best I doubt if that's really what you want to do.

Comment: Because meal has 2 items: the mealName & cost

Comment: That's not an array. That's an object with two properties.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a lot of TypeScript 2/Knockout stuff out there past 2013 it seems, but I did manage to get this to work. I rewrote my TS file for better namespacing (treating it just like an MVC Controller) and, once I did that, the real culprit seemed to be the way I was calling the array elements, as TypeScript changes the way Knockout expects you to do it, evidently. Working from the Knockout tutorial [here](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=collections) it would have you pass the meal name and price to the data-bind as: meal().mealName & meal().price. However, when working from TS, I needed to pass meal as part of the namespace and not a function (*meal().mealName* to *meal.mealName*), which was my main problem. I also moved the ko.applyBindings to the view. Hopefully this helps someone else who got stuck like I did.
The adjusted code is:

```js
/// <reference path="typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/knockout/knockout.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="typings/knockout.mapping/knockout.mapping.d.ts" />

module Index {

 // Class to represent a row in the seat reservations grid
 class SeatReservation {
  name: string;
  meal: KnockoutObservable<any>;

  constructor(name: string, initialMeal: any) {
   this.name = name;
   this.meal = initialMeal;
  };
 }

 export class ReservationsViewModel {

  seats: KnockoutObservableArray<any>;

  // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
  availableMeals = [
   { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0 },
   { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95 },
   { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290 }
  ];

  constructor() {
   //Editable data
   this.seats = ko.observableArray([
    new SeatReservation("Steve", this.availableMeals[1]),
    new SeatReservation("Bert", this.availableMeals[2])
   ]);
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>Passenger name</th>
     <th>Meal</th>
     <th>Surcharge</th>
     <th></th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <!-- Todo: Generate table body -->
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
     <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: meal.mealName"></td>
     <td data-bind="text: meal.price"></td>
    </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
 <script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
   var viewModel = new Index.ReservationsViewModel();
   ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
 </script>
}
```